# How to have instance attribute defined and then persisted across child classes

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to have a instance attribute, `root_path`, persist across my code. I have an `InitialiseStep` class which accepts `root_path`, and when it is defined i.e. by `InitialiseStep(root_path="/test/path/")` I want `CampaignData` to be able to print the value "/test/path/" when I trigger it as part of a pipeline.

A reproducible example should make this clearer...

```
class InitialiseStep():
    def __init__(self, root_path=None):
        self.root_path = root_path

    def execute(self):
        print(self.root_path)


class SparkStep(InitialiseStep):
    def __init__(self, spark=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.spark = spark
        
    def execute(self):
        print(self.root_path)


class CampaignData(SparkStep):
    def __init__(self, spark):
      super().__init__()

      
class Executor:
    def __init__(self, steps):
        self.steps = steps
       
    def run_step(self, step):
        step.execute()

    def run_pipeline(self):
        for step in self.steps:
            self.run_step(step)
        
executor = Executor([InitialiseStep(root_path="/test/path/"), CampaignData(spark)])
executor.run_pipeline()
```

This currently outputs

`/test/path/`

`None`

How can I adapt this code to print?

`/test/path/`

`/test/path/`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not a *class attribute* this is an *instance attribute*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @juanpa.arrivillaga, have corrected.

Comment: In any case, the whole point of an object is to *encapsulate state*, if you want the two instances to share state, you should do that explicitly by what you provide as a parameter. You would have to make `CampaignData` accept `root_path="/test/path/"` and handle it in the `__init__`.  Otherwise, you *could use an actual class variable*, but that would seem inadvisable, because it is relying on mutable class state, which is just slightly better than mutable global state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that `root_path` is an *instance variable*. It belongs to the instance, not even other instances of that class, or any other subclass for that matter.

You *could* use a class variable, that would solve your problem:

```
class InitialiseStep():
    def __init__(self, root_path=None):
        InitialiseStep.root_path = root_path

    def execute(self):
        print(self.root_path)
```

But I would find this design highly inadvisable. I would either bite the bullet and just provide `root_path` everywhere you need it explicitly, e.g., handing it to `CampaignData(root_path, spark)`.

Or probably, you should rethink where this needs to be handled. For example, it could be an attribute of the `Executor`,

```
class Executor:
    def __init__(self, steps, root_path):
        self.steps = steps
        self.root_path = root_path
```

Injected as an argument to `execute`:

```
def execute(self, root_path=None):
    print(root_path)
```

And the executor then can provide it to the Step, i.e.:

```
def run_step(self, step):
    step.execute(root_path=self.root_path)
```

Still, this might make one uneasy, this is making our classes more tightly coupled. Perhaps you just need another way to handle this with some sort of MetaData class.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion suits my use case!